# Implementing non-deprecated tabs in Toolbar?

Tags: android, android-layout

Im trying to implement a tabbed navigation where the tabs are located inside the `Toolbar` and the user can navigate via left/right swipes or tab clicks, just like the Hotel Tonight app:

Screenie:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y29ka.png

Before this would be done using `ActionBar.Tab`, but that has been deprecated. All tutorials and SO questions i've found have only described how to use the new `TabLayout` to put tabs under the `ToolBar`, not inside it. How should I go about implementing this? What would the basic xml layout look like?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using PagerSlidingTabStrip and here you are a tutorial:
https://guides.codepath.com/android/Sliding-Tabs-with-PagerSlidingTabStrip

Comment: Yes ive seen that, but thats to implement a visual feedback for swiping through a ViewPager, and its obviously not in the ToolBar. Also, thats pretty much the equivalant of a `TabLayout` using the Design Support Library.